# How to reconnect to lost VNC server on mac

Tags: macos, ssh-tunnel, vnc-server

I'm using ssh tunneling, vncserver, and the default Mac Screen Sharing app to run a GUI on a remote server (university clusters). It works really well in general, but often if left too long or after moving my laptop to another wifi network (eg, from home to campus) I lose connection to the remote server and Screen Sharing gets stuck in the "Reconnecting" forever.

It appears that the GUI is still running on the remote server because when I write `vncserver -list` in ~/.vnc it still has the .pid file (and I never used the -kill command). How can I reconnect to this vncserver? When I enter `vnc://localhost:59xx` in Screen Sharing it says

> Connection failed to "localhost".
>
> > Make sure Screen Sharing or Remote Management is enabled on the remote computer

I'd really like to reconnect to this remote server because I'm running time-consuming and time-sensitive processes that I need to check the status of from time to time, and I need to make sure that the program successfully saves the output of my program.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I didn't realize that the localhost was based on my IP address, so when I moved locations the ssh tunnel collapsed. All I had to do was recreate the tunnel `(ssh -L 59xx:localHost:59xx -N -f name@cluster.edu` and I was able to reconnect to the port with Screen Sharing.